# How to inject JavaScript in MVC3 Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have got

```
@grid.GetHtml(
   tableStyle: "grid",
   headerStyle: "head",
   alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
   rowStyle: "row",
   selectedRowStyle: "selected-row",
   columns: grid.Columns(
   grid.Column("StartDate", "Start Date", style: "column"),
   grid.Column("EndDate", "Endt Date", style: "column"),
   grid.Column("Title", "Title", style: "column"),
   grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }), style: "column-action"),
   grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }), style: "column-action"))
```

What I want to do is to replace `grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }), style: "column-action")` with

```
<button onclick="$.prompt('Delete',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false } })" title="Delete">Delete</button>
```

How I can do it?

P.S. The final goal is to show popup window YES/NO when we click the DELETE button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a class to the button you can attach an event to it, like this:

C#

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "delete-button" }), style: "column-action"))
```

jQuery 1.7+

```
$(".delete-button").on('click', function() {
    $.prompt('Delete',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false } })
});
```

< jQuery 1.7

```
$(".delete-button").click(function() {
    $.prompt('Delete',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false } })
});
```

Comment: Your approach looks good... But I got the following thing: <a href="/Customer/Delete/e633fd53-00b5-4552-9040-1b0fac0d49bd?class=delete-button">Delete</a>   Could you please say exactly about @class?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I put the style attribute in the route value params. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hmmm you know the event $(".delete-button").  doesn't fire... Do you know where I have to implement it?

Comment: If you're not using jQuery 1.7+ you'll need to use `$(".delete-button").click(function() ...`